# Integer * float = ? in C

Tags: c, multiplication, arithmetic-expressions

What do we get when we multiply float with integer in C? Please explain. I am confused because when I have issues with this when i do Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion and also in many other conversions.

Comment: We get the integer promoted to a float, and the result a float as well. Any decent tutorial should cover that.

Comment: Read data types promotion rule.

Comment: If you have a specific problem, show your code and we can show you how to do it better,

Comment: take alook at page 52 - 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions of [Standard C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: The behaviour can change depending on the compiler and settings, so to be sure that everything works as expected, I would suggest you to perform a cast int auxint = 12; float auxfloat = (float)auxint;

Comment: @qrdl Well, the floating point format, as well as the integer size, may vary between compilers. The implicit type promotion rules remain the same but the value of the result may differ.

Comment: Anyway, to get anything meaningful out of this question as a beginner, you should probably give a specific code case. I would probably not recommend beginners to ponder the details of the various implicit type promotion rules in C, as they are quite obscure.

Comment: @Lundin FP format and integer size may vary between compilers and platforms, no doubt about it, but integer promotion rules are well-defined in C standard.

Answer (score 9):

> *What do we get when we multiply float with integer?*

**TL;DR** We get a floating point result.

To elaborate, for arithmetic operations, if both the operands are of different ranks, according to the arithmetic conversion rules, the operand with *lower rank* is promoted to *higher rank* and then the operation is performed. In your case, the integer is promoted to floating type and the result of the operation if of floating type.

Quoting the relevant parts from `C11`, chapter §6.3.1.8, *Usual arithmetic conversions*

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:

and, for this specific case,

> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is `float`

Answer (score 0):

It's float, but you should pay attention to precision loss, overflow and underflow. recommend read

> IEEE Std. 754-1985. IEEE standard for binary floating-point arithmetic

and also

> D. Goldberg. What every computer scientist should know about
>   floating-point arithmetic [J]. ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR), 1991,
>   23(1): 5-48.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like that I allways cast the minor type (integer) and do the rest of the operation. The result and the operands will be all floating type.